# Artificial player evaluation

Tags: ai

I have a problem concerning a board game I'm creating. I plan on making an artificial player for the game using MiniMax with AlphaBeta prunning, but I'm not sure how to evaluate ir the player is good at the game. Since it's a new game I can't get a player who is good to give feedback. So I'd like to know if there is any technique to determine objectively if the artificial player is actually good. Thank you in advance.

Comment: As the creator of the game, don't you know when a player is good at it?

Comment: Just remember that "good" and "fun" for AI are not always the same!

Comment: We need far more information about the details of the game in order to answer the question of "What is the appropriate metric to differentiate "good" from "bad" in my game?"  In fact, if you, yourself, don't know what metric defines "good" (I assume there are no "wins" or "score"), minimax is likely not the route you'll want to pursue.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that "good" is always a relative term. Good compared to what?

To evaluate the strength of a game AI you need to compare it to other players by letting it play against them. These players can either be humans or other game AIs which were developed independently.

And even then you have only proven that it is good at countering the strategies employed by these players. A player which uses an entirely new strategy might have completely different results.

You can prove that an AI is perfect, when the game is deterministic and the AI is able to calculate every possible game in advance and thus always select the move which results in the best possible outcome. But when the game is too complex for that, you can't mathematically prove its strength.

Comment: You can objectively say that a player that wins all games that are possible to win is "good". As long as some criteria are fullfilled (see my answer) this is actually true for MiniMax - So "good" is not always relative

Comment: Actually you can still prove the strength of an AI if the game is too complex to calculate all possible gamestates, as mathematics doesn't care about our lack of processing power.

Answer (score 2):

Your question, in essence: "Can I rate something without a point of reference?"

No, you cannot.

The game has to be played a certain number of times before you have any reference point at all. Once a certain number of games has been played given one set of AI parameters, you can then, from a human standpoint, gauge the difficulty. And of course you need people -- if only yourself -- to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If a game has perfect information at any point and the game flow is perfectly determinable based upon the finite amount of decisions that could be made, MiniMax with maximum depth will always be the best player in the game(obv. not taking time into account). If you need heuristic approaches and the game does lack some of the properties mentioned above, "good" or "bad" relies on your heuristic.

If your game does not match the criteria mentioned above, you have to try and play against it to improve your heuristic. If it does and time is not a skill-defining factor for a player, MiniMax is objectively "good".